Could Iran have obtained any valuable intelligence from its April 13 attack?
It seems that the Iranian April 13 attack against Israel had mostly political objectives: testing what western powers would and would not do to support Israel and their interests in the Middle East, as well as disclosing the existing military cooperation between Israel and Jordan, and the intelligence sharing with Saudi Arabia (via the US intermediaries.)
However, I wonder whether it could have also provided valuable intelligence, which could be used in future for attacks against Israel or the American/British/French presence in the Middle East. Naïvely - in the past an anti-aircraft battery that was used once, had its location disclosed and would be less valuable. Does the same reasoning apply to any of the means used on April 13? Could any of the airplane, rocket launching sites, or the equipment used have been a secret to Iran prior to this date?
Another possibility - could Iran have learned much about the operational mode of the interception facilities, in order to evade them next time?

This will be quite difficult to estimate with any certainty with only publicly available information. We don't know what Iran knew before and knows now. My guess is that Iran could reasonably have known about the strength of the Israeli air defense system given its past demonstrations and didn't learn much new or valuable. A possible next time would probably end the same way. But who can say these things with certainty? I wonder if this question is really about politics. It seems to be more about military intelligence gathering.

According to Iranian media and analysis, Iran did exactly what it had planned. Their goal was to cause significant economic damage and destroy Israel's facilities, weapons, and bases and show 0.1% of its missile-drone capability to the whole world.

I suppose not, the response was more political in nature than militarily, ... only to convey a political message so that Israelis (and indeed their Western parent in law) will recalculate their strategies; ... otherwise they have had already hacked a number of security sites and, during the years, have already gained the data they need to know for a final war which,  according to their claim if I have understood it right, would terminate the existence of Israel altogether. But who knows for certainty?

No I was wrong, ... after reading others' answers below now I generally acknowledge any new experience is informative anyway for all those who take part or simply witness. But how much valuable be the information gain, whether it will counterbalance the cost, I don't know?

Probably not very valuable. Iran attacked Israel again by missile on October 1st with very limited success. If Iran learned something one would expect that they apply what they learned at some point. The suspicion would currently rather be that the value of anything learned was low.


However, I wonder whether it could have also provided valuable intelligence, which could be used in future for attacks against Israel or the American/British/French presence in the Middle East.
...
Another possibility - could Iran have learned much about the operational mode of the interception facilities, in order to evade them next time?

Absolutely. All of that. Any military operation results in additional information learned by all the participants. The Israelis did an extremely valuable target practice. The Saudis and Jordanians practiced cooperation and coordination with neighboring armies (for Saudis especially this was the first publicly known joint exercise with Israel). Iranians learned about the defense systems involved and their abilities. I'm sure there was a lot of additional intelligence gathered about inter-state cooperation between Israel and its neighbors, communications, electronic warfare, etc.
I think all the armies involved (and some not directly involved, like the Russians in Syria) used this opportunity for as much intelligence gathering as possible, they wouldn't be doing their job right if they hadn't.

Yes, as @littleadv already says, this will be a field day for both sides' intelligence services.
I think one thing not mentioned though, is how Israel's defence explicitly relied on its metropolitan patrons for defence - not from all-out war (in which American military cover was already explicit), but from a single salvo.
Far from a capable self-defence, it was a powerful demonstration of the hand in the glove, of the real powers in play.
The Iranians will be jubilant at this, for it shows (in a mass-market way) that Israel is not independent at all but an outpost of an American axis.
Potentially, even Biden will be content that Israeli society has received a demonstration of "who is the superpower here" (to answer Bill Clinton's rhetorical question following dealings with Netanyahu). Although I don't think the overall fallout is what Biden will have welcomed.
But I think the Israeli administration will have been left reeling, because it punctures claims of "self-determination" and associated Zionist myths and self-image.
It was already unseemly enough to see the begging bowl out for cash and arms over the Gaza situation, though most thought Netanyahu had successfully cast Biden as the subordinate there, and Israelis were still manning the guns and fire controls.
But this time, the dog wagged the tail, not the other way around. And I think that is one of the main effects - it is the widespread publication and demonstration of intelligence that each side already had.

Or, alternatively, one might interpret it as the Arab countries don't care about Palestinians as much anymore, and Iranian threats on them don't work. UAE, Jordan, Saudi Arabia - all cooperated here, not just the US. This is a strong show of lack of Iranian influence in the region, and an example of how irrelevant the Palestinians and their doomed narrative have become. See, I also can spin it to pontificate my point of view.

@littleadv, I don't think the outcome is so simple. The Iranians might have wanted to acknowledge their lack of total power, so that when people say "why aren't you conquering Israel to defend the Palestinians", they can say "because it means conquering America, and Saudi, etc", and then everyone now hums gravely in agreement. (1/2)

Also the fate of the Palestinians is not nearly as important to "Arab countries" as the fate of Israel as a bridgehead for Western power in the region. The Palestinians are supported more widely not out of hand-wringing sympathy for their survival, but out of appreciation of their willingness to keep fighting everyone's common enemy. (2/2)

I really don't understand your logic here, but it doesn't matter because the entire answer after the first line isn't relevant to the question.

@Bobson - If Iran made the conclusions that this answer suggests, it would certainly count as Intel - to do with the degree of Israel's capabilities vs degree of dependence on the US, and how much (if at all) US is able to push back when its own interests diverge from Israel's . These categories of knowledge that could've come to light from the test of events are also more "political" - I.e. relevant to this stack - than questions of military-technical capabilities

@PeteW it's not the first time the US (or the Jordanians) intercepted attacks towards Israel. Goes both ways, by the way, Israel interfered when Syria attacked Jordan many years ago.

That Israel is not militarily independent of US and other Western supporters, was already cleared in the war Israel had ans still has with Hamas (and Hizbollah and Al-Huthis) in a small territory like Gaza (and some relatively small groups around), I don't think this is any news to Iranians.

Also a news to the Iranian could be that Israel is not capable of defending its most important places even with the aid of US, UK, France and etc., as 99% interception lie is gradually questioned in the eyes of interpreters, and the videos taken by cellphones published here or there. Now, Israel is so anxious about Dimona and other sensitive sites, this is certainly a big News to them.
